# Do cats have a preference of being in the light or being in the dark?

Tags: cats, behavior

From time to time I have to put my very energetic cat in my bedroom for an hour or so while I'm cleaning, or working on something I can't have her messing with. In the evenings if the lights are off, it's very dark in the bedroom. Do you think my cat cares whether the light is on or off?

Comment: As long as the light schedule follows what a normal day would look like. For example, if it's dark inside the bedroom but bright outside, you should really turn the lights on.

Comment: While the question is written asking for opinions, it is reasonable to assume that non-opinion based answers can be provided.  The question should not be closed.

Answer (score 4):

Cats are crepuscular, which means they prefer to be awake at dawn and dusk.  As such they've evolved to prefer neither complete darkness or bright light.

That said, human sight is also suppose to be best at dawn and dusk as well.  However, cats proportionally have more rods than cones in their eyes than we do.  (Rods are what give us are ability to see in very low light and their placement in our eyes is why we can see better out of our peripheral vision in very low light.)  Thus cats likely prefer a lower light levels than we do, and are able to see better in darker environments.

Comment: Related [Diurnal, crepuscular, nocturnal, matutinal, vespertine; what do these mean and how do they impact my pet's life?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5806)