# What kind of toys are appropriate for a rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, mental-stimulation

I know rabbits are [crepuscular](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5806/) so it seems like they are either eating, sleeping or spending time with me.  Do they need toys to play with?  If so what kind of toys should I get?

Answer (score 1):

I do have toys for my rabbit. I give her usually paper bags or cardboard boxes or rolls to play with. My rabbit loves spending lots of time with me, however, I still would give them possibly a few toys because they could get bored, or just want something harmless to chew on. I have seen people give plastic toys to rabbits, but I wouldn't recommend it. If your rabbit likes to chew on things, then it could possibly eat plastic which is bad for rabbits's health.

Comment: Actually the plastic bits are tiny and can pass straight through the rabbits system.  Do you have a reference that says otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Mine love tunnels. Google "cat tunnels" and you will find a world of rabbit joy. They also love cardboard boxes, to jump on top of, to hide behind, and to chew.