# Can cats sleep at night?

Tags: cats

As we know, Cats are usually active at night and sleep at noon, but I would like to play with cats at day and sleep with cats at night, is it possible to train cats to sleep at night like human?

Comment: Cats are Crepuscular, Related questions  [Diurnal, crepuscular, nocturnal, matutinal, vespertine; what do these mean and how do they impact my pet's life?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5806)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cats aren't actually most active at night, perse; they are [crepuscular](http://animalquestions.org/mammals/cats/are-cats-crepuscular/), which means they are most active in the twilight hours around dawn and dusk.  This, in nature, primarily has to do with their prey; [mice are also crepuscular](http://www.rspca.org.uk/adviceandwelfare/pets/rodents/mice/behaviour) and birds tend to be active early in the morning (E.G. the early bird, which gets the worm).

The first link also gives information on how you can attempt to change your cat's sleep schedule, but it's worth noting that the two key methods of changing your cat's schedule are the same as changing your own: Food and Activity.

Circadian rhythms are set from light exposure (modifiable via artificial light sources, but irrelevant if you're trying to make your cat sleep during the night), the availability of meals (controllable via your throttling of food bowl access -- put it down in the morning, pick it up at night), and typical activity cycles (play with your cat in the daytime; this also helps to tire your cat out for the hours you're asleep or not at home -- they have a much longer sleep time than we humans do).  (Sources: Wikipedia, personal experience, various websites)

Good luck, and don't be surprised if you end up with a cat alarm clock; they tend to get pushy when their food is withheld until you're awake.

Comment: To reduce feline alarm clock syndrome, I generally have dry food available continuously and give them wet food later in the day and on a somewhat irregular schedule. It doesn't keep my girl from asking that I wake up, but since all she gets out of it is cuddles she isn't too insistent about it.

Comment: @keshlam Growing up, we used to do the 24/7 dry food schedule, and the cats were always active from the afternoon to midnight.  I still hold that feeding the cats around the time you want them to wake up will work.

Answer (score 2):

Cats only sleep whenever they feel like, they don't follow a schedule like we do, they can be playing one moment and then just lay down to nap the next one. So it's no so much about "training" them to sleep, it's more about how their routine with their owners is. In my case, my cats prefer to nap next to/on top of me rather than playing and jumping around. No matter if its day or night.

Answer (score 1):

Cat are not nocturnal. They are dineral - they can be active any time of day or night and sleep any time of day or night.

So, yes, cats sleep at night, and in the morning, and the day, and the afternoon ....

Our cats sleep on the bed with us at night. They have regular spots. Arthur likes to sleep against my back, Murphy sleeps in the crook of my are, Wendy sleeps against my wife....

Most of them come and go during the night. They don't sleep the entire night, though some of the elder ones do spend a large portion of the night in bed with us.

As another answer said, cat's don't sleep one extended time period. They nap all the time. Where do you thing the term "cat nap" came from?

Answer (score 0):

Cats alternate waking and sleeping all day and all night. They don't generally sleep a solid 6 hours or more as we do, but mine certainly spend some time sleeping with and on me. (I need to figure out how to get photos without disturbing them; I'm sure it's very cute.)